# how to find unmodified files linux

Tags: linux, find

I can find the files in a directory which changed the last 4 minutes with the command:

```
find ~ -type f -mmin -4
```

how could I find the files which have not changed the last X minutes?

thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
find ~ -type f -mmin +4
```

sweet, not?

Answer (score 7):

With `!`, which may need escaping in your shell.

```
find ~ -type f \! -mmin -4
```

Comment: +1 because this recipe is more versatile. I _do_ prefer to avoid \! and `-not` for they are _unpretty_ and often confusing to me (especially when also doing `-a`/`-o`, or, god forbid, `-prune`